# Are 'ambiskeletons' viable?

Tags: science-based, xenobiology, anatomy, bio-mechanics

A [recurring problem](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/316/can-you-simply-scale-up-animals?rq=1) in trying to create large creatures is the [square-cube law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square%E2%80%93cube_law#Biomechanics) as it applies to upscaling familiar animals, particularly those with exoskeletons: if you double an animal's size, its weight will increase eight times, but its weight-bearing capacity only quadruples and muscular strength only doubles. Arthropod skeletons already account for a greater proportion of the organism's weight than those of vertebrates.

The largest arthropods in history were the [*Jaekelopterus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaekelopterus) and [*Arthropleura*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthropleura), both about 2.5 m long. But neither rose to more than a few tens of centimetres from the ground.

Among the usual proposed partial solutions are lowering a planet's gravity, increasing the oxygen content of the atmosphere (which allowed for much larger insects in our past), and changing the composition of the skeleton itself. Perhaps a structural solution can be added to this list to make land-based carapaced (rather than [shelled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyptodon)) megafauna plausible.

Would a blending of exo- and endoskeletal traits, an 'ambiskeleton', work? Here is a simplified diagram of what I'm proposing:

[image: Diagram comparing endo- exo- and proposed ambiskeleton cross sections]

<sup>*'Ambi-' from Latin meaning* both.</sup>

The muscle and tissues are encased in a carapace-like shell, with load bearing handled by a bone-like structure along one edge. In this combination the 'carapace' need only contain and protect the contents of the limb or body segment, while the 'bone' bears the weight of the animal. Both portions are continuous, without intervening soft tissue.

With or without the other aforementioned partial solutions, would this allow significantly larger animals with carapaces?

Comment: How is this different from a crocodile? Or actually, from a human? Our skin (and, in the abdomen, the muscular layer) does indeed *"contain and protect the contents of the limbs or body segments"*. And, bonus, there are places in the human body where the bones are placed immediately below the skin.

Comment: @AlexP I think the OP is talking about a thin **carapace** *along with* inner bones. So normal skin doesn't cut it.

Comment: So, like a tortoise, but with even more carapace in place of soft tissues at the paws, tail and head :)?

Comment: It's not a fully formed answer, but look to airframes with a combination of trusses and stressed skins. I believe the term is Semi-monocoque. An endoskeleton is a lot like the skin, using internal structural components to bear the stresses. https://www.cfinotebook.net/notebook/aerodynamics-and-performance/aircraft-components-and-structure

Comment: For a moment there I expected one of the links to be to my profile rather than to wikipedia XD

Comment: Consider what molting looks like. Exoskeletons have difficulty expanding with growth.

Comment: Wouldn't be possible to have everithing double or even triple? For instance you can imagine an organism having two three spines. Perhaps only one transmitting signal and two merely giving support. Something similar to what we have already in arms. For legs one can think of four bones... Something like that was probably not convenient or easy for nature but can be surely be imagined and be consistent with mechanical laws, I think.

Comment: What is your actual end-goal? Are you trying to make giant insects possible, or giant animals in general?

Comment: @AlexP Humans (and crocodiles and most other vertebrates) *do* have external bones - they're called "teeth".  Evolve a creature that grows teeth all over its body and not just in its mouth and there you have it.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Teeth are not bones, they are made from a completely different substance and function completely differently (for example they are not intended to be load-bearing).

Comment: @IanKemp Carapace isn't exactly bone either.  Point is, it's a hard, rigid material that's on the outside of the body, which might be "close enough" for the question.

Comment: @AlexP Crocodiles have osteoderms, bony plates within the dermis, significantly distinct from exoskeletons. Skin is obviously not exosketon-like at all.

Comment: @user3757614 That is a separate issue, but if this produces a positive answer I may propose an approach to growth/moulting.

Comment: @IanKemp Giant insect-like animals; insect-like in that they have what appears to be exoskeletons (rather than bony plates, for example).

Comment: Your real problem is how to let it grow, it can't be shed with internal components and the external components are preventing growth. the carapace and bone have to be separate materials.

Comment: I’m struggling to understand your distinction - insect exoskeletons are literally hardened ectoderm (while vertebrate bones are mesodermal), i.e. skin. Freshly moulted insects have soft skin, which hardens. Any rigid ectodermal structure (nails, scales, horns) is developmentally and structurally an exoskeleton; you just need more of it than most vertebrates have. Glyptodonts are my best guess; feel free to make them shinier, more insectile in looks, etc. And as others mentioned, making the two permanently contiguous gets you into growing troubles pretty quickly: let them split at moulting.

Comment: @Guest Exoskeletons are structurally distinct from scaled/plated/boney dermis and play the weight-bearing role that scales/plates/etc do not. They are similar in appearance and the protection offered, but it ends there.

Answer (score 11):

Although a good question, it does not work except for aestetics which might be your point.

An exoskeleton is designed first and foremost to protect the inside. It needs to be thick enough to provide that protection, if its too thin it will act brittle and break quickly. Skin is relatively easy to repair and its elasticity combined with toughness make it useful to us, but having essentially a thin piece of bone that easily breaks and is harder to repair as your skin would mean you are easily injured and take too long to recuperate from those wounds.

If you make the exoskeleton thicker you run into a problem: it needs to be thick enough to protect but thin enough to not cause your bones to collapse under the weight. We can already crack the shell of a crab, so that thickness isnt good enough. But if you scaled up said crab to our size with a decent thickness to protect it you've already run into the square cube problem you were trying to avoid!

So instead I would suggest a middle-of-the-road solution to your middle-of-the-road solution. You use "normal" bones with skin on the outside, but make that skin look like carapace. Perhaps its more like a horn layer like our nails or the skin of "armored" land animals. Its still skin, its still tough but with a higher flexibility and it just looks like carapace.

Although you might just go with the "it uses another composition" method. Many steps in making Graphene can be done by biological bodies and spiderthread can definitely be made by biological bodies, so having a carapace made from a Graphene skin alloy for both strength and lightweight interlaced with spidersilk for strength and flexibility you can create carapaced megafauna.

For reference, our bones are made of elastines that make the bones flexible and calcium for hardness. When we are young our bones are much more elastine and bones are hard to break, the side-effect is that your bone bends easily and does not protect as much as you want nor does it help when your muscles try to generate power from something that gives way. As we grow older elastines disappear from the bones and mostly calcium is left leading to brittle bones. So making sure you have a solid combination of elastic properties and hardness is vital for a good bone or carapace structure.

Comment: Relative to your "middle of the road to your middle of the road" solution, one word: Calluses.

Comment: Skin made out of spider silk. Now that's not what I expected from World Building. And I love it. Do be wary though - your creature will be hunted to extinction.

Comment: @TheDaleks: Or keratin, that seems to be what all the interesting bits and pieces of a variety of animals are made up of.

Comment: @Demigan Justifying the aesthetics is half of worldbuilding, isn't it? ;D To your point though: I'm not sure it follows that a broken piece of carapace must take longer to recover from than slashed skin, or that the carapace can't have any flexibility—arthropod joints are still covered in chitin. AFAIK young insects can heal cracks, and adults repair damage with a moult; there are options.

Comment: @rek a small insect crack has a much smaller surface area than a small crack on megafauna. A deep gash in skin can heal in 2 weeks while small bone breaks (completely surrounded by tissue!) Take 6 weeks to 6+months. That is a lot of time to walk with a wound. On top of that the outer carapace would need to be so thin that accidentally hitting a tree as you walk could create large cracks because its so brittle. That is why I think you should make it aestetic or go for metamaterials.

Comment: @JohnDvorak I wouldn't make the top of the skin out of spidersilk and never use purely spidersilk. Rather I would let the skincells in the lower skin regions pull the spidersilk threads between them to create a mesh with these cells embedded inbetween. many spidersilks are like Kevlar and some are much better than Kevlar so you would have a high resistance against cuts and stabs so anyone trying to hunt these creatures would better be ready to try and bludgeon it to death or bring a lot of force behind their cutting implements.

Comment: @Demigan Why would the outer carapace need to be that thin and brittle? Healing is a bit outside the scope, but part of the reason bones take so long to repair is mineralization, which doesn't begin for weeks into the healing process. A non-mineralized carapace wouldn't follow that process; chitin is sugar fibres, keratin is protein. And the carapace need not be the totality of protection from damage.

Comment: @rek because of the weight. For example chitin weighs aproximately 1.4 g/cm^2 and normal skin about 1g/cm^2, which I assume has a basic third dimension to it like 1mm thickness. In the meantime "normal" bone you need for beings as large as us is between 2.9 and 3.8g/cm^3 (hard to compare I know). That added weight makes it hard to create megafauna, so just aestetics is the best you could go for unless you can find plausible metamaterials and such to use. Skin is pretty much a super-power by itself and I tried formulating questions about it but its so damn complex!

Comment: @Demigan I think that cuts to the core of my question, an assumption that x% of an exoskeleton is there to protect the meat inside, and y% to support the weight of the animal. If the two roles can be separated (or partly so), perhaps the protective portion needn't be as thick as assumed because the 'bone' can thicken to take the weight.

Comment: And at the other end of the spectrum, some of the largest land animals today have incredibly thick skin: 2.5 and up to 5 cm for elephants and rhinos, respectively.

Answer (score 10):

## Already done

Turtles have their shells as a part of their skeleton somehow - it's made of <strike>leather</strike> keratin but the ribs are fused to it.

One extinct species called [archelon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archelon) could be 460 cm long (about 15 feet, I figure). Here's a picture of one's remains with a human by its side:

[image: An archelon skeleton with a human poking it]

Comment: Nonsense, these are normal vertebrates, the "shell" is bone. Evolutionary spoken the shell developed from the ribs, not "leather" which is an artificial product anyway.

Comment: @a_donda well, it's still an "ambiskeleton", no?

Comment: Well, depends how the ambi-part is defined. Turtles (and Glyptodons) are vertebrates, they don't combine an arthropod-style carapace with a vertebrate style skeleton. Everything is imaginable in world-building but hard to imagine how an insects metabolism and body blueprint and a mammal's could find together. Science based i'd go for keratin (horn, fingernails, hair) for a shell. Those vertebrates know how to make :-)

Comment: @a_donda I've double checked, turtles (mostly) don't have leather shells, they're made of keratin.

Comment: Turtle shells are made of bones. They may have a keratinous overlay, reptile style because that's what they are. It is not an ambisceleton like envisoned in the question because that (seems to me) tries to combine boney interior skeleton with chitinous exoskeleton of athropods. That doesn't (to my knowledge) exist. Chitin is too soft to support great weight. And I am only raising the finger because it's tagged "science based", else anything goes of course :-)

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw As fused bones I'm not sure turtle shells qualify as arthropod-like carapaces, and they're within the dermis rather than truly exoskeletal.

Comment: Reading the description of the Archelon it doesnt seem to be a good answer. The OP wants a way to build land-based megafauna, but the Archelon was (thought to be) sea-based. Even if it did come on land it would rest lying down and push itself forwards rather than be able to stand upright. So applying it to a megacrab for example wouldnt work.

Comment: note turtle limbs are still like normal vertebrate limbs, bone only on the inside., also there is living tissue on the outside of the shell bone, no part of the bone is in contact with the outside.

Answer (score 2):

An ambiskeleton would work in theory. The joints for both the internal and external structures would have to be lined up, in order to allow mobility. And having more hard, sturdy parts would definitely increase your creature's defensive abilities, and would give it more of a chance to exist in spite of its large size.

Comment: The proper place to vent is Meta. Other than that, interesting answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like ambiskeletons require specific features that no one living creature have, but maybe some extinct creatures could had had them, the placoderms, a clade of extinct fishes in which almost the half of their body was covered by bone plates and for what I know, the soft tissue over the plates was minimum, thing which is important for the purpose of the "ambiskeleton, which is to permit big and massive arthropod like creatures with an apparently hard exoskeletal body.

[image]

As I mentioned these creatures had very little integument on the bone pectoral and skull plates (at laest just a thin skin layer at specific parts), which would easily reveal their tough appearance. Other thing is that they had most of the organs and muscles inside the boen plates and not out or over.

Other possible point to this "model" is that placoderms even underwater could reach bigger sizes than biggest arhtropods, with one of the biggest species having moderated estimations till to 6-7 meter long and the upper estimations with even to 10-11 meters.

So to had those big sizes is a possible evidence or solution respect to the problem that size is limited by having all its organs contained within a rigid exoskeleton which I've seen is usually mentioned for giant arthropods. Basically looks placoderms could grow without be limited by its armor.

And some amazing thing, a specific group of placoderms went farther, developing arthropod like limbs from its pectoral fins.

[image]

The following image is from a little size genre but others were able to reach to 2-3 meters long.

And the part which contribute to the "ambi" part is that placoderms kept a spine contained inside their armor, only connecting with their braincase, practically being an only internal muscle anchor point.

**Trouble points to consider**

These were acuatic creatures, so the more probable case is that all extra weight provided by the armor were sustented by water, that could cause problems on land for be so heavy. So would be necesary to determine how thick it could be before reaching a limit where it falls under its own weight.

Possible solutions for this are to use strange materials, or the evolving some estructural construction able to support the weight. Like this [diabolical beetle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQwUiX_eUFs) or the [mantis shrimp exoskeleton](https://phys.org/news/2016-05-mantis-shrimp-ultra-strong-materials.html).

And things that I'm really not sure of how they work, like the biological mechanism by which these animals could grow within their armor without shedding as arthropods would, I have assumed that by a stacking of layers of bone dissolving into the lower ones as they grew.

And the mechanic part, I don't know if the surface provided together by the minimum internal skeleton and exoskeleton would be enough to anchor a sufficient amount of muscle to be able to move on land. So is that, to find how much surface muscles require.

The only thing we can know is that this "model" worked satisfactorily underwater.

By my part I would try to search for solutions or make questions to solve the last incovenients.