# Seating in Integrated Cities - Not all humans, different species

Tags: fantasy-races, urban-fantasy

Okay, so, I have different species than the ones for, well, most of my questions ([This](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/190955/rail-transportation-with-races-described-below-specifically-seating) is the first question of the series), but the purpose is still here. However, it's on an alien planet, called Damarian. Also, most species are part of the same species, *Nakar Sapiens*, as different subspecies.

Here are the new species I have:

**Volrorthean:** A divided species of gigantic *Nakar*, *Nakar Sapiens Volrorjotunus*, that averages either 12 or 14 feet tall.

**Maravnean, Asterian, Amazonean, and Madraean:** Four different subpecies of *Nakar Sapiens*, *Marav, Asteris, Amazoneus, and Madrae*, respecively, which are this planet's equivalent of humans. All four subpecies are roughly human height (5-6 feet tall).

- Maravneans lay eggs
- Asterians have 4 1/2 month pregnancies,
- Amazoneans are all female (But can still have genetically diverse children)
- and Madraeans *look* all female, but the subspecies has, and I repeat, ZERO sexual diversity, with only a pathetic, hidden penis differentiating males from females.

**Fenirean:** This tiny subspecies, *Nakar Sapiens Fenrirus*, is only 2-3 feet tall, with most being on the short end of that spectrum.

**Phanerae:** From the old list, *Nakar Sapiens Phaneros* is 7-8 feet tall and hauntingly beautiful (And thicc/muscular) to other humanoids.

**Elves:** The *Nakar Sapiens* subspecies of *Altas, Silvanus, Eladris, Aquatis,* and *Undros* are 5-ish feet tall. The subspecies represent the D&D elf subraces of High, Wood, Eladrin, Sea, and Drow, respectively.

**Dwarves:** *Nakar Sapiens Dwarro* is a unified species, when referring to only the Hill and Mountain Dwaves. Duergar, *Nakar Sapiens Duerg*, are a separate subspecies. Typical members of either subspecies are 3-4 feet tall.

**Orc:** *Nakar Sapiens Orkrus* is a large, brutish race, 6-7 feet tall, grayish, and with large tusks.

**Tieflings:** This fiendish subspecies, *Nakar Sapiens Infernos*, is the same as the Tielfing from D&D, plus the variants from the Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide and subraces from the Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes. Each subrace is more of a variant or breed, while winged tieflings, those with the Feral Ability Score Increase, or those with the Hellfire trait are part of a different subspecies altogether (*Nakar Sapiens Abyssos*), due to those tieflings being descended from daemons, not devils.

**Aasimar:** This angelic subspecies, *Nakar Sapiens Celestes*, appears human, but has magical properties similar to angels. The Protector and Scourge subraces are Celestes, while Fallen are genetically different enough to be a separate subspecies, *Malarvis*.

**Aeritheans:** A different species than the others, *Nakar Aeritheus*, is the species of Earth humans, who came on a generational ship to Damarian to settle and explore.

That's all of the *Nakar Sapiens* subspecies. Except for Tieflings, none of the above subspecies have tails, wings, or non-human body plans. Here are the rest of the species, with species names.

**Avari:** This species of felid obligate carnivores, *Navris Sapiens*, has a cat-like tail and short, sheathed claws in the fingertips. Not much else.

**Naven:** This genus, *Gerbo*, is an herbivorous species with three species: *Elkis*, the skittish deer-like humanoids, *Buris*, a bull-headed minotaur-like subspecies, and *Loksis*, the elephant subspecies.

**Maer:** This old list species, *Maeris Sapiens*, is a mermaid-like species with legs and a big, chunky fish tail that can only move via dolphin-like tail movements, leading to smacking noises when on land.

**Formians:** This species, *Formrican Sapiens*, is an ant centaur. 2-3 feet tall.

**Vaeran:** Also from the old list, *Vaeris Sapiens* is a four-armed sapient grasshopper species, 4-5 feet tall.

**Arachne/Drider:** This species, *Tarantla Sapiens*, is a spider-taur, 5-6 feet tall, with a 6-8 foot leg span. [This](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/51903/anatomically-correct-arachne?noredirect=1&lq=1) is a link to the Anatomically Correct page on this site about Arachne. Read the accepted answer for what the will look like. They have hair by pure blind luck, skin over their chitin plates (Extra protection), and not too hairy on the human body, but both genders are hairier than an Aerithean.

**Pterians:** From the old list, *Ikran Pteris* are 6-7 feet tall with 4-5 foot long tails and huge mountain banshee wings (From the alien Avatar, with the blue people - look up "Ikran wing" on your browser). The tail has a fan at the tip for flight control and is highly flexible.

**Taur Races:** Four taur races, all from the old list, all 6-7 feet tall and 8-10 feet long. They are: Ashara (*Draco Kentaurus*), Centaurs (*Kentaurus Sapiens*), Leonar (Navris Kentaurus), and Zavran (Tarantla Scropius).

**Mitarn:** This raptor species, *Deinonychus Sapiens*, is 4 feet tall, 8 feet long, and can sit low or high. Has a tail.

**Ceana:** This half-human, half-snake species, *Yuantis Mraelvis*, is 13 feet long but usually raises their top 5-6 feet (With the top 2-3 being a human's torso). They can coil their tails and use is as a beanbag-esque seat.

**Kobolds:** This small reptile species, *Draco Minoris*, is 2-3 feet tall and has a lizard tail.

**Dragonkin:** This species, *Draco Sapiens*, is 6-7 feet tall and is basically the Dragonborn race from D&D, but hey have tails.

With all of these races, it would be expensive to make many seats accommodating one species.

One way around this is to make low seating (Like on cushions) and table. The problem is that Volrortheans are too tall. The other is to go on the path the of Final Fantasy and put everyone in the same chairs, but accommodate for the more extreme body plans.

**Also, due to a comment from the user sphennings, I will add this: The seating I am talking about are supposed to be not attached to the floor, e.g. restaurant chairs, school desks, office chairs, bar stools, and even how normal chairs and tables are sold as household furniture.** I don't want to have Japanese kotatsu seating, due to the Volrortheans, but I want there to be the ability to move chairs around, like what happens in restaurants, schools, and homes. This means that a family of 8 (Or a waiter/waitress) can take a few chairs (And possibly a table piece) from a nearby table without busting out power tools (Like what would happen on a train, should a chair be taken out; the train seats are bolted to the floor); I want the chairs and tables to be highly mobile, as in being able to be picked up and carried across a room without power tools being required or a human-sized humanoid being exhausted.

Does anyone else have better ideas than this?

Comment: While your creatures are different, this looks substantially similar to your previous question.

Comment: @sphennings This is about seating in not trains, but the following: restaurants, schools, offices, and other places where one is not in a moving vehicle (Like trains or planes). This can even mean how tables and chairs are sold.

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to make it clearer how this question is substantially different from your previous question? It seems like both questions are asking about how a society could deal with a menagerie of different creatures seating needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Cushions & Boxes:

Bypass fixed furniture all together and have a giant pile of cushions, pillows, and bean bags. That way, each species can come into an establishment and grab or request what they need. Helpful wait staff adjust things as needed if they want a good tip (guessing some species don't tip well and will get worse treatment). Make the stuff tough to deal with sharp points/boney protrusions and waterproof (with optional small swimming pool-like structures so species needing water or who are especially messy have some containment).

If desired, a pile of leather-covered wooden crates in various sizes could be substituted for/added to this, allowing more support for those who desire it. But if a giant chitinous thing wants a tiny pillow, or a tiny humanoid insists on a six-foot-tall box and a ladder (so they can stare their giant date in the eye) who are we to judge?

If folks are especially fussy, you can have some folding furniture for very particular needs (that new species needs to tuck their tail + venomous stinger in a lock to keep from accidentally killing other patrons).

Comment: Thank you DWKraus! this is exactly what I need! +1 for the great ideas, plus the humorous Zavran/Arachne wanting a Fenirean-sized pillow or a Fenirean wanting a Volrorthean-sized box and a ladder to make eye contact with their Volrorthean-chan!

Comment: Nice edit! No more killing people by tail with fancy-schmancy furniture!

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting allows for it, smart furniture/ seating. If its scifi, just have it be a modular transformer type seating arrangement that accommodates all the different species.If its a fantasy setting, magic shapeshifting furniture. I could easily see using either magic or some vague science/tech explanation working for what amounts to giant bean bags that mold to users physical form and preferences.