# Racial slurs for multi-species nations: Specifically, modern age countries

Tags: society, fantasy-races, races

This is a new question for Damarian's species: Link is [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/200768/seating-in-integrated-cities-not-all-humans-different-species) if anyone would like a description.

***Story time***

So, the setting is on Damarian, some years after a world-shaking event called the "Arrival", which is the colloquial name for the arrival of a generational ship filled with an alien species similar to *Nakar Sapiens*, which were called the Aeritheans, or *Nakar Aeritheus*.

However, the Aeritheans had a secret: THEY'RE OUR SPECIES. The Aeritheans are Earth humans who came to Damarian to settle and explore the stars. However, to the sapients down below, these aliens had come from a strange land, and was so altering to their societies that a new calendar was made, starting at the year 0 NGT, or Nruka Grat Tankira, "After The Arrival" in the local common tongue of the landing site, not to be confused with the last year of the new calendar, -1 MGT (Maukr Grat Tankira, "Before the Arrival").

Immediately after first contact with the Aeritheans, people had mixed reactions. Some traded, some fought, some worshiped the arrivals as angels and demigods, just as their ancestral stories foretold.

However, after the luster of being new wore off of the Aeritheans, everyone saw them as being no more powerful as the older species, just possessing more advanced technology. Years later, Aeritheans had become integrated nearly everywhere, and the Aeritheans had done the same, accepting Damarians into their cities with open arms. Or, at least, seemingly open arms...

***Question time***

Okay, as the last sentence said, the Aeritheans weren't all too happy about Damarians being introduced to their homes and workplaces. Soon after Aeritheans got ahold of (Slightly inaccurate) information, racist people shifted their focus on other Aeritheans (Who didn't seem as strange anymore, after 12 generations living and working together on a giant ship) to the "aliens" invading their homes.

So, what I should have said for the question was, ***What are some racial slurs for the inhabitants of Damarian?***

This means any Damarian species (Not Aeritheans) can get a racial slur. As there are a ton of them, I don't need y'all to give me an exhaustive list of every slur you can think off (Though that's a good thing if you do, and I might accept it just for accepting's sake). Just give me a few that might be common.

***Slurs can include:***

- Anything directly insulting a species, such as a rude name for a species with an odd body part (Calling Pterians "GMO dino-chickens).
- Anything insulting a species' society without actually targeting the species ("Oh, I would love to be an arrogant, skittish Evereskan so that I can make art all day and not care about anything else" in a mocking tone (PS: Evereska is a city on Damarian populated mostly by Tolimean high elves: They're known to be flighty and love art, but they can come off as pricks when talking about their artistic culture))
- Anything belittling interspecies relationships (Which are kind of disliked by Damarians too)(("Why would you even like a Ceana, Lexi? They don't even have d***s.")(Or: "Dating a Madraean guy still makes you a lesbian or straight, 'cuz they look like women")

Feel free to add any other slurs you can think off!

PS: ***THIS IS NOT MEANT TO INSULT ANYONE!!! I'M ONLY MAKING THIS QUESTION FOR A BOOK AND I'LL NEED SOME SLURS FOR PLOT REASONS! I'M NOT CREATIVE AND I NEED YOUR HELP!!!***

Comment: Pick up any distinct element of their look or stereotypical image. Speak it out aloud with contempt and disgust. There, you're done, most of the real-life slur was born that way.

Comment: I vote to reopen. There is indeed a lot of story information in the question. However the question itself is about story background rather than events, so it falls under the heading of Worldbuilding. Perhaps it would be reopened if you removed all the story details. It would be enough to describe the various species and then ask for potential slurs.

Comment: @DarthBiomech Ideally something with only one or two syllables. It's easier to say short words with contempt.

Comment: Asking for the name of anything (diminutives, names of days, name of planets, basically anything the constitutes a proper noun) is always reason to close a question. It's always story-based, or opinion-based, etc. It's just an aesthetic. It's like asking what color paint would be best on your aliens' houses. You're not asking about a rule or system of your world - you're literally asking about storybuilding. If the question were reopened by vote, it would be closed again by the mods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pterodactly people are called **flappers**. Because they flap their wings and because the word sounds rude. It can also refer to the female genetalia.

Elves (or any small and graceful species) use **slurs for effeminate or homosexual men**. This also works for any of your species that all look female.

Fenireans (miniature people with or without wings) are called **fairies**. This was already a slur for homosexual men, that passed to tiny people for obvious reasons.

Orcs (or any large burly species) use **slurs for developmental disorders**. This comes from how they have different facial proportions than the standard human. For example a wider face, larger forehead or heavier jaw, that might also lead to slower or slurred speech.

Dwarfs have two main types of slurs. Either about living underground. So **hole-digger** or **dirt-fucker**. Or something about being hairy. Ideally you want something short that gets across the idea that their whole body is covered in pubic hair. On this theme, they are also called **crabs** or **lice**.

Avari (cat-people) usually take **cat** (or **pussy**) as a racial slur.

This works for any half-animal people. Just refer to the person as the name of that animal. Or make the sounds associated with those animals. They don't like that.

Kobolds and dragonborns are called **lizards**. Kobolds are sometimes called **newts, worms, rats or vermin.** Dragonborn are also called **boots** short for "pair of boots waiting to happen".

Cat people are called **crotch-lickers** or **milk-drinkers** (from Skyrim).

Dog people are called **ass-sniffers** or **shit-eaters**.

It's also common to insult cat/dog people by claiming they shed their fur or urinate everywhere, like normal cats/dogs.

Baseline humans are called **apes.** It's common to claim they throw their own dung. You can also piss-off a human by making ape noises and beating your chest at them.

Minotaur people are called **milkers** which is especially offensive since the normal cow is a farm-animal. This also insults male minotaurs since you are also calling them girls.

Elephant people are called **d*ick face** for obvious (and stupid) reasons.

Insect people are called **bugs** or **buggers**. The latter is more offensive for obvious reasons.

Phanerae: These guys are 8 feet tall and look like Greek gods. In our world we might call them all [**Arnold**](https://www.wallpaperflare.com/static/273/372/998/arnold-schwarzenegger-bodybuilder-gyms-muscular-wallpaper-preview.jpg) as an insult.

Tieflings: They have horns and hooves so are sometimes called **goats**. Common insults centre around how goats will eat anything. "Chewed any good fenceposts recently, goat?"

Comment: I applaud you for making up some hilarious slurs. No offense to anyone out there, winged or otherwise. ;)